# Monetize pirate apps

Tags: ios, app-store, currency

My game is heading to release and so I'm starting to think about making some profit from it. As of now, I'm planning to make it a paid ios-app. What I'm interested in is how can one monetize pirate copies? I'm sure one can do it, as ustwo studio (Monument Valley authors) shared some statistics, and noted that they could earn more than 500k$ on pirate copies.

Of course, the first thing that comes to my mind is detecting a jailbreak and then show some ads. But what if user has a jailbreak but still bought a copy legally?

So what ways do you know to make profit from pirate ios apps?

Answer (score 1):

As you've correctly pointed out a jailbreak does not imply that your app is a pirated copy and since jailbreaking is legal in most countries nowadays you would offend those power users running a legal copy on a jailbroken device. I guess you would also break your side of the contract to not display ads in paid versions.

Basically you've already answered the question yourself:
"Display ads only on pirated copies".

Although your question was not specific about detecting pirated apps you might get some input here regarding the detection possibilities:
https://github.com/Shmoopi/AntiPiracy/blob/master/SFAntiPiracy.m

Otherwise you should ask a new specific question (after researching existing answers) about piracy detetion possibilities.